# freecodecamp Challenges- Seek and Destroy

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this challenge Seek and Destroy. I can't figure out what is wrong. Any help ?

Seek and Destroy
You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements from the initial array that are of the same value as these arguments.

This is the initial code below:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

This is my Code below:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var letsDestroyThis = [];
  var i =1 ; while (i<arguments.length) {
    letsDestroyThis.push(arguments[i]);
    i++;
  }
  
  for(var j=0 ; j< arguments[0].length; j++) {
    for (var k= 0; k< letsDestroyThis.length; k++) {
      if(arguments[0][j] === letsDestroyThis[k]){
        arguments[0].splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return arguments[0];
}

destroyer([2, 3, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  /* Put all arguments in an array using spread operator and remove elements 
     starting from 1 using slice intead of splice so as not to mutate the initial array */
  const args = [...arguments].slice(1);
  /* Check whether arguments include elements from an array and return all that 
     do not include(false) */
  return arr.filter(el => !args.includes(el));
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an array of all values that are supposed to be removed. Then use `Array.filter` to filter out these values.

Note: `Array.splice` will change original array.

```js
function destroyer() {
  var arr = arguments[0];
  var params = [];

  // Create array of all elements to be removed
  for (var k = 1; k < arguments.length; k++)
    params.push(arguments[k]);
  
  // return all not matching values
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return params.indexOf(item) < 0;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values

    var args = Array.from(arguments);
    var filter = [];

    for (i = 0; i < args[0].length; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < args.length; j++) {
            if (args[0][i] === args[j]) {
                delete args[0][i];
            }
        }
    }

    return args[0].filter(function(x) {
        return Boolean(x);
    });
}

console.log(
    destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

//two ways of resolving the Seek and Destroy challenge on the FreeCodeCamp
 //I was trying to simplify this code, please post your solutions, simplifying the code
 //as much has its possible

```
 function destroyer1 (arr){
    //get array from arguments
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.splice(0,1);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     for(var j = 0; j < args.length; j++){
        if(arr[i]===args[j]){
        delete arr[i];
        }
     }
 }
return arr.filter(function(value){
    return Boolean(value);
});
}
```

//--------------------------------------

```
 function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  //Get values from arguments of the function to an array, index 0(arr[0] will be "arr", 
  //rest of indexes will be rest of arguments.

  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < args[0].length; i++){
    for (var j = 1; j < args.length; j++){
        if(args[0][i] === args[j]){
            delete args[0][i];
        }
    }
  }
  return args[0].filter(function(value){
    return Boolean(value);
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
console.log(destroyer1([1,6,3,9,8,1,1], 3,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my Code:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var argsBeRemove = [...arguments];
  argsBeRemove.shift();
  return arr.filter(val => {
    return argsBeRemove.indexOf(val) == -1;
  });
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of Seek and Destroy. I assume that there are no zero elements in input (that assumption allows to pass the challenge). But that way I can make found elements equal zero and then just filter them out. It is pretty straight forward and no index mess when deleting elements in for loops.

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
    // Remove all the values
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    var temp = [];
    temp = arguments[0].slice();

    for (j = 1; j < args.length; j++) {

        for (i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) {

            if (arguments[0][i] == arguments[j]) {

                temp[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    function isZero(value) {
        return value !== 0;
    }

    var filtered = temp.filter(isZero);

    return filtered;
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function destroyer(arr) {

     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
     return arr.filter(destroyNum);

     function destroyNum(element) {
         return !args.includes(element);
     }
}
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Comment: Try to explain your answers. It gives more clarity and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, it is way less convoluted:

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  // arr1 is equal to the array inside arr
  var arr1 = arr.slice(arguments);
  // arr2 becomes an array with the arguments 2 & 3
  var arr2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  // this function compares the two and returns an array with elements not equal to the arguments
  return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function(item) {
    return !arr1.includes(item) || !arr2.includes(item)
  })
}


destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You will be provided with an initial array (the first argument in the destroyer function), followed by one or more arguments. Remove all elements **from the initial array** that are of the same value as these arguments.

The accepted solution returns a new array, instead of removing the elements from the existing array.

This can be achieved efficiently by iterating the array in reverse and removing any elements matching any of the filter arguments.

```js
function destroy(original, ...matches) {
  if('length' in original) {
    let index = original.length
    while(--index > -1) {
      if(matches.includes(original[index])) {
        original.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }
  }
  return original;
}

const original = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
destroy(original, 2, 3)
console.log(original);
```

Comment: Best solution, but people solving freecodecamp challenges won't understand var-args. You might want to explain it more clearly.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat What are you referring to as "var-args"? [The rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)?

Comment: Absolutely. . .

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to previous one, but I didn't use `indexOf`. Instead of that I checked the values in cycle, but compiler gives me a warning to not to declare function in cycle.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values
var temp = [];
for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    temp.push(arguments[i]);
    arr = arguments[0].filter(function(value) {
        return ( value !== temp[i - 1]) ;
    });
}
return arr;
}
destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the arguments behind the array, which are the number required to be removed and store them to a list. Then, we can just use a filter to filter out the numbers that needed to be removed.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
 let removeList=[...arguments].slice(1);
 return arr.filter(e=>removeList.indexOf(e)===-1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add some description about the code. Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to try to identify the answer to "what concept(s) is the OP missing?" and then supply some explanation that helps them to understand the problem, rather than just posting a cut-and-paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know isn't the shortest way to do it, but i think is the more simple to understand in an intermediate level.

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...elements) {
  var i =0;
  while(i<=arr.length){                    //for each element into array 
    for(let j =0; j<elements.length; j++){ //foreach "elements"
      if(arr[i]==elements[j]){             // Compare element arr==element
        arr.splice(i,1);                   //If are equal delete from arr
        i--;                               //Check again the same position
        j=0;                               
        break;                             //Stop for loop
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
   return arr;
}

console.log(destroyer(["possum", "trollo", 12, "safari", "hotdog", 92, 65, "grandma", "bugati", "trojan", "yacht"], "yacht", "possum", "trollo", "safari", "hotdog", "grandma", "bugati", "trojan"));
console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function destroyer(arr) {
let newArray = Array.from(arguments).splice(1)
  return arr.filter(item => !(newArray.includes(item)))
}
```